# Pymysql cant connect Amazon RDS host, but same host is accessible through mysql workbench

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, pymysql

I am using pymysql to connect to Amazon RDS and it fails with :

```
 db = pymysql.connect(host=Host, user=User, password=Pswd, db=DBN, charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor,local_infile=True)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 107, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1045, u"Access denied for user 'p_cs'@'xx.xx.xx.xx' (using password: YES)")
```

**However If i try to connect to the same host with mysql workbench, I am able to!** Any help on what can be the connectivity issue??

Comment: Also, using the pymysql code that is written I am able to connect my localhost as well, but when i change to aws it fails!

Comment: Viv - did you ever resolve this issue?  I am seeing the same problem.  

EDIT: upon searching further, this might be it:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44271782/flask-sqlalchemy-pymysql-access-denied-error