# Flask-SQLAlchemy PyMySQL - Access Denied Error

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, pymysql

OS: RHEL
Python Version: 3.6
SQLAlchemy Version: 1.1.10
PyMySQL Version: 0.7.11
MySQL Distrib: 5.7.17-13

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='testuser', passwd='###########', db='mysql')

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT Host,User FROM user")

print(cur.description)

print()

for row in cur:
    print(row)

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

When I try to execute the above code I'm getting the following error message, but I'm still able to connect to mysql using the same account and password via command line.

```
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'testuser'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)")
```

I tried searching all over the internet for this error message but I could not figure out the actual issue. I would really appreciate if anyone could help me fix this issue.

Comment: Well, have you created a db user with that name and password?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes, I have, and I'm able to login from command line using the same user and password.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue: The default auth plugin for MySQL 5.7 was sha256 which is not supported by PyMySQL. Changed it to mysql_native_password and that fixed the issue.

Comment: I faced a similar issue in the past, and I could not solve this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42347191/pymysql-cant-connect-amazon-rds-host-but-same-host-is-accessible-through-mysql?noredirect=1&lq=1. Where can we change this ine - "Changed it to mysql_native_password "